# ASP.Net Core 3.1 view model changes on post

Tags: post, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I have a very peculiar problem in my hands...

I'm writing a management webApp for my company to manage jobs, timesheets and a bunch of other things...

I have this view where I can edit a previously inserted job in a SQLite database and I can add or remove a scope of supply from that particular job...

I have a problem though...

The page on GET is loaded with all the correct info from the database.
At the bottom of the page I have a table object where each row is a scope of supply and at the end of each row a button is added programmatically to remove that scope from the job and that calls an action in the controller that receives the model, removes the item from  List object inside the model and then returns the view "EditJob" with the modified model.

And that works great the view updates as it's required to and I successfully removed the scope from the job graphically...
Once I go to click the Update Job button though something very weird happens...

Let's say that in my table I had in the first row Scope01 and in the second Scope02...
I press remove on Scope01 and the view updates showing me only Scope02 as the only item in the table and with breakpoints I see that the model passed to the view has infact the correct data in it.

Once I press update job the action POST EditJob that is called at from submit by a button receives a model that is all correct but the list of scopes has only one item as it should but the wrong one it only has the one I removed!!! what the heck is happening? I don't understand...

This is the markup and c# for the tble in my view:

```
@if (Model.Data.JobScopes.Any())
{
    <table class="card-table table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">ID in SQL</th>
                <th scope="col">Descrizione</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Data.JobScopes.Count; i++)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.Data.JobScopes[i].Id)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => Model.Data.JobScopes[i].Id)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.Data.JobScopes[i].Description)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => Model.Data.JobScopes[i].Description)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button asp-controller="JobAdministration" asp-action="RemoveScopeFromJobOnEdit" asp-route-id="@i" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Rimuovi</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}
```

This is my remove scope action:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult RemoveScopeFromJobOnEdit(int Id, EditJobViewModel model)
{
    model.Data.JobScopes.RemoveAt(Id);

    return View("EditJob", model: model);
}
```

And this is the final post action that actually updates the job in the DB:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> EditJob(EditJobViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var job = await DbContext.Jobs.FindAsync(model.Data.JobId);

        if (job == null)
        {
            ViewBag.ErrorMessage = $"La commessa con l'ID = {model.Data.JobId} non è stata trovata";
            return View("NotFound");
        }
        else
        {
            job.JobId = model.Data.JobId;
            job.JobName = model.Data.JobName;
            job.JobDescription = model.Data.JobDescription;

            foreach (var modelScope in model.Data.JobScopes)
            {
                if (!DbContext.JobScopes.Where(scope => (scope.JobId == model.Data.JobId) && (scope.ScopeId == modelScope.Id)).Any())
                {
                    var scope = await DbContext.Scopes.FindAsync(modelScope.Id);

                    DbContext.JobScopes.Add(new JobScope
                    {
                        JobScopeDescription = modelScope.Description,
                        ScopeId = modelScope.Id,
                        Scope = scope,
                        JobId = job.JobId,
                        Job = job
                    });
                }
            }

            foreach (var dbScope in DbContext.JobScopes.Where(scope => scope.JobId == model.Data.JobId))
            {
                if (!model.Data.JobScopes.Where(scope => (scope.Id == dbScope.ScopeId)).Any())
                {
                    DbContext.Remove(dbScope);
                }
            }

            DbContext.Jobs.Update(job);

            var result = await DbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

            if (result > 0)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("ListJobs", "JobAdministration");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "L'operazione di aggiornamento è fallita!");
            }
        }
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

Ignore the few italian writings they are just visual aid...

Thanks for any help! :)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem but I have no idea if it's the advisable solution or not really...

I used TempData property to Json-serialize and Json-deserialize my model being thrown around the actions and it seems to fix the various shenanigans that were happening before...

Is it a valid solution?